# Mark Jenkins builds red/yellow depending on test/integration-test failures

Tags: maven, junit, jenkins, integration-testing

I have a Jenkins build configured (project uses Java, Maven, JUnit). Depending in what Maven phase the unit tests fail I want to mark the build as Red, Yellow or Green:

- compilation errors : Red
- failure(s) in Maven phase "test" : Red
- failure(s) in Maven phase "integration-test" : Yellow
- Successful : Green

How would I do that?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like the [Jenkins Text Finder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) plugin to parse the logs for specific patterns.  That should work for basic needs.

If you need something more complex (sounds like you might) you could look into the [Groovy Post Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) plugin and do this with a Groovy script.  The script would still parse the console log, but gives you a lot more flexiblity and allows you to add custom messages to the build page.

Something like the following would probably work:

```
class ChangeResult {

    static def run(manager) {

        if(manager.logContains("Some compilation error")) {
            manager.addWarningBadge("Compilation Error")
            manager.createSummary("warning.gif").appendText("Build failed due to compilation error", false, false, false, "red")
            manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.FAILURE
        }
        if(manager.logContains("Some integration error")) {
            manager.addWarningBadge("Integration Error")
            manager.createSummary("warning.gif").appendText("Build unstable due to integration error", false, false, false, "red")
            manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.UNSTABLE
        }
    }
}
```